# Not understanding basic routes of Laravel php framework

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am learning Laravel 5. I have installed it successfully . My OS is ubuntu 14.04. Following [this](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing) to learn laravel.

I have written these codes in app/Http/roures.php:

```
Route::get('/foo', function()
{
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

Going to localhost:8000/foo   i see *Hello World*. That's ok.

Now, I replaced the above codes with the following codes:

```
Route::post('foo/bar', function()
{
    return 'Hello World';
});

Route::put('foo/bar', function()
{
    //
});

Route::delete('foo/bar', function()
{
    //
});
```

Then, how I will be able to access to **post**  or **put** or **delete** routes? I mean what should be the url ?

Comment: Route::get('foo/bar', function()
{
    return 'Hello World';
});

Answer (score 1):

You don't change the URL, it depends on what the HTTP request was.

When you navigate to /foo/bar the request you are using is GET.

If you POST a form with the action set as /foo/bar then your POST route takes effect.

So bottom line, same URL, different METHOD.

Answer (score 0):

The URL will still be '/foor/bar' from your application.

Symfony router (which is used by Laravel framework) has to trick the parameters to work correctly when you want to access URL through PUT/PATCH/DELETE/POST request.

You will has to pass a '_method' parameter with the different type of request you want to do.

ex

```
Route::put('/foo/bar', function(){ return 'PUT method'; }); // Accessed though /foor/bar with a PUT request
{'_method':'PUT'}
```

or

```
Route::delete('/foor/bar', function(){ return 'DELETE method'; }); // Accessed though /foor/bar with a DELETE request
{'_method':'DELETE'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Since HTML forms only support POST and GET, PUT and DELETE methods will be spoofed by automatically adding a _method hidden field to your form.
```

Unlike GET routes, PUT, DELETE, POST are alike.

To quickly create a form for a put request you could do to this:

```
Route::put('foo/bar', function()
{
    //
});
```

You could do this in your view:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar', 'method' => 'put')) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Or If you don't like using the Form Builder, you need to add a hidden field in your html form like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">
```